# Add values from JSON output on JavaScript variable, fail on Loop or Async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, asynchronous

I need to get the languages of array  lenguajes[]  from JSON and store  in a "custom_lenguajes" variable , but I don't get.

JSON output:

```
{
-   data: 
[
-   {
    DT_RowId: "row_93",
    idiomas: "Si",
    site: "342800010",
    lenguajes: 
    [
     -  {
         id: "3",
         code: "nl"
        },
    -   {
         id: "5",
         code: "ja"
        },
   -    {
         id: "17",
         code: "de"
        },
   -    {
         id: "19",
         code: "en"
        },
   -    {
         id: "38",
         code: "ru"
        }
    ]
    }
],
    options: 
{},
    files: [ ]
}
```

JS code:

```
var custom_lenguajes ="";
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page-1', function() {  
// get lenguajes. START
        $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v134/lacarte.restaurants.front/alacarte/php/languages.front.php", { site: id_establecimiento()}, function(data){
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
    data = data['data']; 
    data3 = data; 
});

    //  I need create a variable that acummulate languages from JSON, this way: "nl,ja,de,en,ru"
        $.each(data3, function(entryIndex, entry) {
             $.each(this.lenguajes, function() { 
                 alert(this.code); // don't show nothing. ONLY TEST
                    custom_lenguajes += this.code + "\,";
                    console.log(custom_lenguajes);  //show "". ONLY TEST
             }); 
          });             

// get lenguajes. END
...
```

For your help:

- if I use console.log(data3);  ( on my code )  I can see an  empty object “[ ]” on console chrome, when load the page
- After, (when page is loaded) ,   if I write on  console chrome:  data3[0].lenguajes[0].code , its show me "nl" . On chrome console look it's works, but not on my code.

What are doing wrong? Is a problem with my loop or with ASYNC?

Any help are welcome!
Thank you!!

Comment: put the `each` inside the `getJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is asynchronous which means that it will not wait for your ajax `$.getJson()` function to finish before attempting to go in to the `$.each()` loop.  Try putting youre loop inside the `$.getJson()` function.

```
var custom_lenguajes ="";
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page-1', function() {  
    // get lenguajes. START
    $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v134/lacarte.restaurants.front/alacarte/php/languages.front.php", { site: id_establecimiento()}, function(data){
        for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
        data = data['data']; 
        data3 = data; 

        $.each(data3, function(entryIndex, entry) {
            $.each(this.lenguajes, function() { 
                 alert(this.code); // don't show nothing. ONLY TEST
                 custom_lenguajes += this.code + "\,";
                console.log(custom_lenguajes);  //show "". ONLY TEST
             }); 
        });   
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.

Yes, your comments are in good direction (loops inside $.getJSON) , now its works!!
The final code that works:

```
    $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v134/lacarte.restaurants.front/alacarte/php/languages.front.php", { site: id_establecimiento()}, function(data){
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
    data = data['data']; 
    data3 = data;

    //  I need create a variable that acummulate languages from JSON: "nl,ja,de,en,ru"
        $.each(data3, function(entryIndex, entry) {
             $.each(this.lenguajes, function() { 
                 //alert(this.code); // ONLY TEST
                    custom_lenguajes += this.code + "\,";
                    //console.log(custom_lenguajes);    //ONLY TEST
             }); 
          });   
});// end  $.getJSON
```